# Parenthetical sentences

Tags: punctuation

I have a colleague who, in his technical documentation, sometimes likes to put entire sentences, or sometimes entire paragraphs, in parentheses. This looks wrong to my eye, but I'm having difficulty articulating precisely why. Should I be more tolerant of this style, or is there a reason why comments in parentheses should generally be restricted to phrases within a sentence and not form larger units of text?

In case this isn't clear, here's an example, adapted from some text I'm reviewing:

```
By default, the template to be rendered will be $root/template. (Variable 
$root has a default value.)

(Previous versions of this program loaded templates from webapp/WEB-INF, 
but in this release these files have been moved out of the web application.)
```

I think the goal here is to de-emphasise the subsidiary information, but I think it would be clearer without the parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have indicated, the purpose of parentheses is to de-emphasize the enclosed material. There are a variety of techniques that can be used, depending on the style of the publication. Italics are also used to set off content as different (although they are often used for *emphasis* rather than *de-emphasis*). Changes in font are also used.

Parentheses can be placed around single words, phrases, complete sentences, or even complete paragraphs. There is nothing that specifically defines the limits, although using them around several paragraphs grouped together would be unusual.

The usual reason for using parentheses around a full paragraph is the need to logically cover the material at that point in the narrative, but to make sure that the reader understand that the content is not part of the main body of information. In fact, parentheses are often used in place of footnotes. While footnotes make clear that the information is an aside, they can be distracting or annoying to many people, and seem very formal.

This is really a style question, but the simple answer is **no**, there is nothing wrong with your colleague's approach. However, you are free to eschew this technique and find other ways to convey the relative importance of various content.

Comment: Anecdote. But when i was studying mathematics paranthetical paragraphs tended go in brackets ("[") rather than paratheses ("(")

Answer (score 4):

I tried to look this up in style guides just now, after an editor called it out in something I had written. I wasn't able to find any that discourage it, and a couple that suggest that both options are acceptable.

Searching for “parenthetical sentence” gave for example [page 524 of *Writing: A Manual for the Digital Age*](https://books.google.com/books?id=y3I6Bbp8h9cC&lpg=PT553&pg=PT553), in which Example 3 illustrates it (while Example 1 has the other alternative):

[image: writing]

Similarly, there are a couple of mentions of this in the [*Chicago Manual of Style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Manual_of_Style). In the 16th edition (2010), section 6.13 (under “Periods”, covering 6.12 to 6.15) says:

> [6.13] ***Periods in relation to parentheses and brackets.*** When an entire independent sentence is enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, the period belongs inside the closing parenthesis or bracket. When matter in parentheses or brackets, even a grammatically complete sentence, is included within another sentence, the period belongs outside (but see also 6.96). Avoid enclosing more than one complete sentence within another sentence. For the location of a period with quotation marks, see 6.9.
>
> > Fiorelli insisted on rewriting the paragraph. (His newfound ability to type was both a blessing and a curse.)
> >
> > Farnsworth had left an angry message for Isadora on the mantel (she noticed it while glancing in the mirror).

Note the first example above. Section 6.96 (under “Parentheses”, covering 6.92 to 6.96) says (note the fourth example below):

> [6.96] ***Parentheses with other punctuation.*** […] A question mark, an exclamation point, and closing quotation marks precede a closing parenthesis if they belong to the parenthetical matter; they follow it if they belong to the surrounding sentence. A period precedes the closing parenthesis if the entire sentence is in parentheses; otherwise it follows. (Avoid enclosing more than one sentence within another sentence; see 6.13.) […]
>
> > Having entered (on tiptoe), we sat down on the nearest seats we could find.
> >
> > Come on in (quietly, please!) and take a seat.
> >
> > On display were the watchmakers' five latest creations (all of which Shellahan coveted).
> >
> > Five new watches were on display. (Shellahan coveted the battery-powered quartz model.)
> >
> > Strabo is probably referring to instruction (διδασκαλία) (Jones et al. 2008).

Comment: The first pic is so helpful. I will save that for later.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'rule' that entire sentences should not be put in parentheses (these things - dashes and commas can also be used to delimit parenthetical statements, but would obviously be inappropriate for parenthetical sentences). One 'may' even put entire chapters, I suppose, inside the things - the grammatical rules are that

(1) the material inside the brackets conforms reasonably well to grammatical standards and is reasonably clear and pertinent

(2) the parenthetical statement can be omitted with minimal disruption (some would say no disruption) of the grammaticality of the matrix material

However, you're quite right - punctuation is here to serve, not dictate. I personally have no problem with parenthetical sentences in general, and can't see there being much problem with a whole paragraph (on a single page!). A chapter would be stretching it a bit. Of course, even grammatically acceptable parenthetical statements or other strings (be they single words or longer) might actually muddy the waters rather than clarify.

Your particular example would be confusing (a distinct possibility with nested, and, as here, series, parentheses) were it not for the further formatting (paragraphing).

I actually think your colleague's style is helpful (here at least), emphasising, as you imply, the main point, but providing vital-when-needed background material that can be glossed over when not needed but easily accessed *when* needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've belatedly remembered that, many years ago in a technical writing class, the tutor claimed that parentheses can draw the eye and hence, paradoxically, emphasise what should be de-emphasised. Does that seem plausible? I'm wondering if that's why I dislike the example I'm reviewing.

Comment: It's probably a true claim. As with other aspects of communication, use of parenthesis is a two-edged sword. And exposure desensitises - the more you see that annoying format (/ hear that weird expression...), the more acceptable it tends to become. The main alternatives - sections with subsections, subsub- ..., italics, different fonts, tables, footnotes ... - also have their weaker points. I tried colour-coding quotes from different sources in a post once, and confused everyone (including myself).

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I am guilty of this myself, but I try to minimize it in formal writing.

Paranthetical commenting is okay, so long as they adhere to all the other rules of grammar and punctuation.  Including these full sentences in two separate parenthetical comments is a bit unweildy, but not unallowed by the rules (and he seems to be consistent with his paranthetical punctuation as well).