# Capital letter in parentheses after full stop

Tags: capitalization, parentheses

I am writing up a project and I am wondering whether or not I would capitalize the first letter in brackets where the brackets are the start of the sentence.
For example, consider the following: I like French. (Not really).
Should it be (not really) or (Not really)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally, you want to start a sentence with a capital letter. Have you reviewed the topics of capitalization and sentence formation? You might find more help at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you are putting your comment in parentheses *as you have stated in the example*, I would start the phrase with a capital letter, and put the period *inside* the brackets. However, with a short parenthetical statement like that, it *can* be written: I like French (not really). Or I like French. (Not really.)

Comment: (Also) are you concerned with the case where the sentence begins with a parenthetical but doesn't end there?

Comment: heh nice Bradd  :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, if you "do have a full stop", then the next sentence in braces has a capital.

If you "don't have a full stop" it's part of the same sentence, do not, ever, use a capital. (And the full stop goes "outside everything.")

Both forms are completely normal, OK and commonplace.

> Here's an example of a sentence (with some extra stuff).
>
> Here's a great sentence. (Didn't you love that sentence?)
>
> Here's a sentence (it sucks) with short words.

That's all there is to it, no biggie here.

Answer (score 0):

I have always treated parenthetical statements as part of the sentence, and always as additional commentary to what has just been stated.  With that rule in place, there would never be a parenthetical statement starting a sentence.  Your provided example, using my rule, would not put the period after the word French, but would be placed after the contradictory statement just after that word. See below:

> I like French (not really).

Comment: That's one way to do it, but there's nothing wrong with having parenthetical sentences.

Comment: Yeah, whole sentences in parenthesis are completely normal. (Here's an example.) They are everywhere and in all historical periods of writing.

Answer (score -5):

You shouldn't put a complete sentence in parentheses at all.

Comment: I don't like being critical, but you should provide authoritative references. [Start here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127707/parenthetical-sentences) and check the accepted answer. Then look [here](http://www.wmich.edu/writing/punctuation/parentheses). Then work on your Google-fu for awhile.

Comment: Who says.......?

Comment: You forgot to put your sentence in brackets.

Comment: There's a big difference between 'You may put a complete sentence in parentheses' and 'You must put a complete sentence in parentheses'.